# Populating input fields with database info relative to selection from drop down menu

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a form. In the form I have a drop down menu of peoples names populated from a database. The rest of the form is made up of a few input fields, address, phone, email. This info is also stored in the same database. What I want is when you select a name from the drop down menu the rest of the form fields fill automatically/dynamically with that persons relative data. No refresh, no submit, no go to another page the fields just populate. I think it's an ajax request I need maybe an onChange function on the form but I'm just not sure. Don't want to use jQuery just javascript. I haven't had much success with this and it's driving me mad. Any help would be appreciated. Here is a snippet of my code from the form :

```
            <option value="" selected="selected" class="firstLine">select a name</option>               

            <?php $query = "SELECT * FROM customers ORDER BY id ASC";

              $run = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

              while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)){ 

              $row['fullname'] = $row['first'].' '.$row['surname'];?>

              <option value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>"><?php echo $row['fullname']; ?></option><?php } ?>

        </select>

        <input type="text" name="address" id="address" value="" disabled="disabled"><br />          

        <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" value="" disabled="disabled"><br />

        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" disabled="disabled"><br />
```

Comment: where is your `onChange()` and `ajax` attempt? there are many examples in the Related links on the right. Also, will you be using plain vanilla javascript or the jQuery library?

Comment: Just using plain vanilla javascript don't want to use jQuery for this. I know I can put onChange in the option tag but how do you script that function and populate the forms?? Thanks Sean.

Answer (score 0):

An approach I take often is to create a small getData type of service endpoint.

for example in php: *but you could easily do this in c# like I did in the following link.
http://chadcollins.com/json-service-output-from-sql-select-using-c/

1. create a /services/getData.php file and inside it:
2. ensure the page only runs if session is authenticated / check authentication
3. connect to your database and execute the query to the db by passing the sessionUserID into your select.
4. echo the response in json format
5. use jquery to handle the ajax (it will be a bit of code do it with native js, but ok if you want.
6. on the onChange() event in your UI, consider using ajax method to call your  services/getData.php script
7. then using that returned json collection of json data, loop the data and assign the values to your form fields by id.

Notice in my example script how I print out the format needed for a JSON ajax read call. If you want example php code let me know and I can probably pull something together.

Comment: I need just php and javascript code no jQuery. If you have an example of that I would greatly appreciate it, thanks.

Comment: Hi @JohnH . I will see what I can come up with tonight. Ive started an example method using raw javascript for ajax request. Feel free to check out this example. If you follow the model I describe this should work for you. http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-make-ajax-requests-with-raw-javascript--net-4855

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to do

```
    <option value="" selected="selected" class="firstLine">select a name</option>               

                <?php $query = "SELECT * FROM customers ORDER BY id ASC";

                  $run = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

                  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)){ 

                  $row['fullname'] = $row['first'].' '.$row['surname'];?>

                  <option value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>" onchange="getdata()"><?php echo $row['fullname'];?></option>
    <input type="hidden" name="addressinfo" value="<?php echo $row['address']?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="phoneno" value="<?php echo $row['phone']?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="emailid" value="<?php echo $row['email']?>">

    <?php } ?>

            </select>

            <input type="text" name="address" id="address" value="" disabled="disabled"><br />          

            <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" value="" disabled="disabled"><br />

            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" disabled="disabled"><br /> 



now you can use javascript to populate the value to those input boxes
<script>
function myFunction() {
var phone= document.getElementById("phoneno").value;
 var address = document.getElementById("addressinfo").value;
var email= document.getElementById("emailid").value;
document.getElementById('phone').value(phone);
document.getElementById('email').value(email);
document.getElementById('address').value(address);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code here but this does not seem to work. It leaves one name in the drop down options field and the rest of the names outside and below the drop down field. Plus none of the input fields are dynamically populated. It's a head scratcher!!

Comment: @sagar chapagain your response isnt correct nor is the approach. Why would he use javsacript in this way... The best approach is to use an ajax request response approach.

Comment: @ChadCollins :Properly see the question.I know we can use jquery-ajax to   get the deserved answer but please look at the question properly he has asked to solve using javascript and not jquery so I am using this approach.

Comment: @sagar chapagain, I saw the question, and gave a link below to a raw javascrpt XML/HTTP request approach no jquery... Its your example that I found to be completely incorrect syntactically and as an approach.